# How to deal with the problem of multi-page printing caused by sending string with "\n" to Microsoft Print to PDF

Tags: c

Below is part of my code：

```
unsigned char *printbuf;
int printlen = 0;

printbuf = malloc(64);
memset(printbuf, 0, 64);
memcpy(printbuf, "aaaaaaaaa\n", 10);
printlen += 10;
memcpy(&printbuf[printlen], "bbbbbbb\n", 8);
```

Then i call Microsoft Print To PDF to print the string

What i want is:

```
aaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbb
```

and i want the content to be printed on one page，but the final result is that the content is printed separately on two pages,one page for one row.

I guess the printer will split a new page when it encounters "\n"

I tried replace to other control charactor but it didn't work,it seems to only recognize "\n" but not any other control charactor

Comment: Please post an [mcve].

Comment: What happens if you do the simple `printf("aaaaaaaaa\nbbbbbbb\n");` ?